# Сумма элементов подмассива

Tags: php

В переменной лежит такой массив

```
Array ( 
  [1] => Array ( 
      [1] => 4 
      [5] => 7 
  ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
      [1] => 2 
      [5] => 5 
  ) 
  [3] => Array ( 
      [1] => 2 
      [5] => 5 
  ) 
  [4] => Array (
      [1] => 6 
      [5] => 9 
  )
  [5] => Array (
      [1] => 6 
      [5] => 8 
  )
)
```

Вопрос, как можно посчитать сумма элементов с индексом [1] и с индексом [5], во вложенном массиве, без хардкода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришел только 1 вариант, возможно есть вариант проще:

```
function array_counter($in) {
    $out = [];
    foreach ($in as $array){
        foreach ($array as $index => $value){
            if (array_key_exists($index, $out)){
                $out[$index] += $value;
            } else {
                $out[$index] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Пример работы функции:

```
$array = [
    [
        1 => 4,
        5 => 7
    ],
    [
        1 => 2,
        5 => 5
    ],
    [
        1 => 6,
        5 => 9
    ],
];

var_dump(array_counter($array));
```

Вывод будет:

```
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  int(12)
  [5] =>
  int(21)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, какой тут может быть хардкор, но самый простой способ, вероятно, будет следующим.

```
$sum = [1 => 0, 5 => 0];
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$sum){ $sum[$k] += $v; });
```

callback-метод функции [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php) в качестве параметра получает значение элемента и его ключ. Если значение само явялется массивом, то на обработку оно не попадает, поэтому на конечную функцию всегда попадают только пары с ключом `1` или `5` с их значениями.

*upd:*
в случае, если набор ключей массив может меняться, необходимо проверять их наличие:

```
$sum = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function($v, $k) use (&$sum){.
    if(!array_key_exists($k, $sum)){
        $sum[$k] = $v;
    }
    else{
       $sum[$k] += $v;.
    }
});
```

Comment: А что делать если в массив будут добавляться новые элементы, постоянно добавлять в `$sum` новые ключи?

Comment: @cruim задача описана весьма конкретно. Есть массив такого вида, и надо посчитать сумму конретных ключей. Когда задача будет другая (а вы пишите принципельно другую задачу), то решение тоже будет другим. Если вас просят решить квадратное уравнение, вы скажете формулу дискриминанта, или будете выводить универсальное решение для уравнений степени N ?

Comment: @cruim ах, да это ваш вопрос оказывается. Вы пишите в условии, что ключи могут меняться, если оно так.

Comment: может я неправильно сформулировал. дело не в том,что ключи могут меняться(у уже существующих элементов), новые ключи будут появляться при добавлении новых элементов.

Comment: @cruim да без разницы когда они появятся. Для такой задачи важным является только то, ключи фикисрованы и статичны. Либо могут меняться. Ответ впрочем расширен для произвольных ключей, хотя уже не такой элегантный как для фиксированного набобора. Хотя если есть возможноть инициализировать массив суммы в другом месте динамически, то ничего не изменится.

Answer (score 0):

Есть специальный для этого метод `array_sum`

```
$a = [
    [1 => 4, 5 => 5 ] ,
    [1 => 3, 5 => 6 ] ,
    [1 => 2, 5 => 7 ] ,
    [1 => 1, 5 => 8 ] ,
    [1 => 0, 5 => 9 ] ,  
];
//сумма всех значений колонки 1
$b = array_sum(array_column($a , 1));
//сумма всех значений колонки 5
$c = array_sum(array_column($a , 5));
//сумма всех значений 
$d = array_sum(array_map('array_sum' , $a));
print_r([
    $b, $c ,$d  
]);
```

На выход :

```
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 35
    [2] => 45
)
```